# Ignoring file 'libdvdcss.lis' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/'

Tags: 14.04, apt

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.
Every time I update my comp,I got

```
N: Ignoring file 'libdvdcss.lis' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'libdvdcss.lis' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

I am giving ls output from sources.list.d

```
getdeb.list                          libdvdcss.list                            videolan-stable-daily-trusty.list.save
getdeb.list.save                     otto-kesselgulasch-gimp-trusty.list       webupd8team-java-trusty.list
gnome3-team-gnome3-trusty.list       otto-kesselgulasch-gimp-trusty.list.save  webupd8team-java-trusty.list.save
gnome3-team-gnome3-trusty.list.save  playdeb.list                              webupd8team-y-ppa-manager-trusty.list
google-chrome.list                   playdeb.list.save
libdvdcss.lis                        videolan-stable-daily-trusty.list
```

When I try this

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ rm libdvdcss.lis
rm: remove write-protected regular file ‘libdvdcss.lis’? yes
rm: cannot remove ‘libdvdcss.lis’: Permission denied
```

EDIT
I have done the same,just I have first entered as  a root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apt-sources in the sources.list.d directory need to end in `.list`.

When in doubt... look at `man sources.list`, and you'll find the following:

> The /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory provides a way to add sources.list entries in separate files. The format is the same as for the regular sources.list file. File names need to end with .list and may only contain letters (a-z and A-Z), digits (0-9), underscore (_), hyphen (-) and period (.) characters. Otherwise APT will print a notice that it has ignored a file, unless       that file matches a pattern in the Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently configuration list - in which case it will be silently ignored.